# ReRender issue in SelectList

Tags: slds, selectlist

I am facing issue with re-rendering the Select List, based on the option selected in another select list. This is a working piece of code in normal VF tags and styling. When I changed the VF page to SLDS style I am facing the rerender issue. I can see the selectOptions are prepared in controller but VF page fails to re-render. In the code below, the selectList with id 'dependent' should populate/refresh based on the selected option in selectList with id 'base'

```
    <div id="divPDT" class="slds-form-element__control" rendered="{myCondition}">
<div class="slds-select_container">
    <apex:selectList id="base" value="{!MyController.pdt}" size="1" styleClass="slds-select" > 
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!MyController.pdtOptions}"/>
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!MyController.selectPdt}" rerender="divPdt, divPlt"
        status="editPlanPanelStatus"> 
        </apex:actionSupport>
    </apex:selectList>
</div>
</div>

<div id="divPLT" class="slds-form-element__control" rendered="{myCondition}">
<div class="slds-select_container">
    <apex:selectList id="dependent" value="{!MyController.plt}" size="1" styleClass="slds-select">
        <apex:selectOptions  value="{!MyController.pltOptions}"/> 
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!MyController.otherAction}" status="editPlanPanelStatus">
        </apex:actionSupport> 
    </apex:selectList>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `apex:outputPanel` instead of div?

Comment: Reshma, all these div's are inside a outputpanel. And when I rerender the panel, the selections are lost, so I am rerendering only div. But I am not sure if that's the correct solution, as there are some conditions when I need to rerender the entire panel. The entire panel rerender works fine when there are no SLDA tags involved and the rerender issue issue comes only with  SLDS tags.